# How to work around check for `sites/default/files` during Drupal installation, if you're not planning on using it?

Tags: 8, files, installation

I'm working with a server where I don't have shell access and I've dropped the database in an attempt to reinstall Drupal (having run into issues with a failed deployment). When I try to step through the Drupal install process on the server, during the "Verify requirements" step, I get this error:

> FILE SYSTEM: Writable (public download method) - The directory sites/default/files does not exist. An automated attempt to create this directory failed, possibly due to a permissions problem. To proceed with the installation, either create the directory and modify its permissions manually or ensure that the installer has the permissions to create it automatically. For more information, see INSTALL.txt or the online handbook.

We're using the S3FS module, so we don't really need the `sites/default/files` directory, once the site is up and running. I've run into this issue before in other environments where I do have shell access and I was able to create the directory from the command line and continue the installation process. At first, I thought I'd add an [(almost) empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository/932982#932982) directory to the site's repository and redeploy; however, we have a cleanup script that deletes all `.gitignore` files prior to deploying. I could presumably add a `DoNotDelete.txt` file or something, but is there a "cleaner" way to work past the error message?

Comment: I think the files directory has to be created nonetheless. S3 is used for uploaded files, isn't it? But Drupal core or contrib maybe needs to create folders or files for temp storage or caches in the files directory.

Comment: "We're using the S3FS module, so we don't really need the sites/default/files directory"
you 100% do need that directory for more then just uploaded files .. get your host provider to ensure correct permissions on the these ->  sites/default/*